# resharper "cannot resolve symbol absmiddle"

Tags: resolve, error-suppression, resharper-5.1

I have resharper 5.1. When I analyze "Errors in Solution" I get a lot of the same error in my aspx files. The error is:

`cannot resolve symbol 'absmiddle'`

It occurs on a line of code like this:

```
<img src="image.png" align="absmiddle" />
```

How do I suppress this 'error' so it doesn't come back on when I restart Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In visual studio with resharper:

- You should get a lightbulb in the left hand side of the screen when you click on one of these `absmiddle` attributes.
- click on the lightbulb and select the *Inspection Options for ...* from the list.
- In the dialog that comes up, select how you want to treat these errors.

In any case, you should not be using the `align` tag let alone a value of `absmiddle` with that tag. Instead, add this to your CSS:

```
img.absmiddle { vertical-align:middle; }
```

of couse, you'd need to set the `class` attribute for the images you want centred to `absmiddle`.

Comment: I don't get a light bulb on that error. (align='absmiddle' may not be standard, but it works. I will take your suggestion and use it. Still, my question isn't resolved. thanks.)

Comment: I've added an alternate suggestion for you.